# Please help me adjust this script to load External XML instead of local

Tags: php, xml

i need help to edit this PHP script. Currently it looks for the most recent XML file on the local server, but I wish to make it load a specific XML file from another server.

```
    define('XML_LOCATION', "../"); //relative to this file
```

...
...

```
function load_xpath($dir=XML_LOCATION) {
    if ($_REQUEST[SORTORDER] == DEFAULTSORT) {
        //$dom = new DOMDocument;
        //$dom->load($this->latest_xml_file($dir));
        $dom = $this->load_xslt($this->latest_xml_file($dir), $this->xslprops[LENGTHDESC][XSL], $this->xslprops[LENGTHDESC][SORT]);
    }
    else {
        $dom = $this->load_xslt($this->latest_xml_file($dir), $this->xslprops[$_REQUEST[SORTORDER]][XSL], $this->xslprops[$_REQUEST[SORTORDER]][SORT]);
    }
    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $xp->registerNamespace(NS, "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5");
    return($xp);
}

function load_xslt($xml, $xsl="", $sort_order="ascending") {
    $domxml = new DOMDocument;
    $domxsl = new DOMDocument;
    if ($domxml->load($xml) && $domxsl->load($xsl)) {
    //if ($domxml->loadXML($xml) & $domxsl->loadXML($xsl)) {
        $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
        $proc->importStylesheet($domxsl);
        $proc->setParameter(NS, 'sortorder', $sort_order);
        return $proc->transformToDoc($domxml);
    }
    else {
        //TODO: decide on error out method
    }
}

function latest_xml_file ($dir=XML_LOCATION) {
    $xml_list = array();
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if (preg_match('/.*\.xml$/i', $file)) {
                    array_push ($xml_list, $dir.$file);
                }
            }
            closedir($dh);
        }
    }

    rsort($xml_list);
    return $xml_list[0];
}
```

Im sure a whole lot of that code is not needed, as I dont need it to work out the most recent file,  just load in an external file.
For example:  https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/ae0324ff-e1a5-4a77-9783-f41248bfa975/boats   would be the external XML.

I dont really know php or xml...  but im sure if someone can help me change the code it would all work fine !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$remoteFile = file_get_contents('https://services.boatwizard.com/bridge/events/ae0324ff-e1a5-4a77-9783-f41248bfa975/boats'); 

function load_xpath($remoteFile) {
    $dom = $this->load_xslt($remoteFile, $this->xslprops[LENGTHDESC][XSL], $this->xslprops[LENGTHDESC][SORT]);
    $xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
    $xp->registerNamespace(NS, "http://www.starstandard.org/STAR/5");
    return($xp);
```

}